# Heroku log for Resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, heroku, backgroundworker, resque

I'm using Heroku + RedisToGo + Resque. I have a worker which is running a non-ending task. I'd like to have a log of its activities. `heroku logs --tail` doesn't show any information regarding the worker activities. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Did either of the suggested answers work for you?

Comment: @trliner you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yeah, my answer below works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku logs anything written to standard out or standard error. So a simple `puts` statement should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like `Rails.logger.info("I am done doing stuff!")` inside your Resque worker's `#perform` method.